# Hiding property setters while using an OR Mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent-NHibernate to manage all the data persistence layer and I am overall very pleased (and grateful to the NHibernate community).  I plan on continuing to use OR mappers.  I've developed an API around the POCOs that are being mapped.  The downside is that all the properties are both gettable and settable by the UI developers; when what I really want is to hide properties from non-middle tier development and only show the provided API methods to perform operations.

Does anyone have a good strategy for this?

Overly simple example:

```
member.FName = "Julian";    /// Don't do this because it avoids the my checking
member.LName = "King";


member.setName("Julian", "King");   /// Yes - this will throw an error if this person already exist
```

Comment: What's the difference between public setters and public operations? Both yield the same result.  Maybe you want to make your types _immutable_ instead?

Comment: By operation do you mean method?  Are you suggesting use Methods instead of Properties?

Comment: Yes. No.  It sounds like you want immutable types in which case you would pass everything into a constructor.  Thus there would be no setters or methods to change state.

Comment: Truth be told I just want to hide some public properties from the autocomplete.  That would probably be 99% effective.

Comment: You can't do that when it's the same class.  You could make a 2nd class that shared state for use by say the UI tiers that didn't have the setters

Comment: You don't have to use setters at all. You use backing field and set up your mapping to use backing field. Our domain almost never exposes any setter outside of domain. All state changes are done through commands.

Comment: Do you have a brief example of a "backing" field.  I am not even sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string _fName;
public string FName
{
   get { return _fName;}
}

private string _lName;
public string LName
{
  get { return _lName;}
}

public void SetName(string fName, string lName){

   // check for nulls here and or validate pre-conditions

  _fName = fName;
  _ lName = lName;

// check for post conditions here

}
```

or better yet use value object (see definition of value object in DDD)

```
public void SetName(Name name){

      _fName = name.FirstName;
      _ lName = name.LastName;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  You are correct that this would protect the data properties and force the use of the function to set Name.  However, maybe I didn't make this clear, I am using an OR mapper Fluent NHibernate and so having a private or no setter at all will throw a mapping error.

Comment: You might want to read up on NH little bit more. You can map to private fields columns. I do it all the time.

Comment: You can specify it even as a convetion for all classes or on case by case bassis. DefaultAccess.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(CamelCasePrefix.Underscore);

Comment: You are right.  I tried mapping with private setters and Nhibernate threw an error.  At that point I assumed that it was not something that wasn't supported.  Thank you for the correction.  I'll vote this as the right answer.

Comment: Sharing the official Fluent NHibernate document on how:  https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties